# Installing Yum via SSH on a server hosted by GoDaddy

Tags: linux, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux

The problem is that GoDaddy's RedHat Linux hosting fails to come with either `apt-get` or `yum` pre-installed for package management. I need either of those to get started on installing java and other utilities for a Minecraft server using my GoDaddy hosting.

I have tried to manually install and compile yum, which might have succeeded if I knew more about this. The bash console I am using includes python, install, and any other basic command you can think of, the most important is wget. It seemed like yum was missing a dependency and I tried to compile that, which seemed to work but never got yum it's an extra command that it needed, I fail to remember its exact name right now.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might be better off as a support ticket on your GoDaddy account. It's a bit old, but they have a how-to https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-make-a-minecraft-server/

Comment: Adding a package manager is not something you should have to do yourself on _any_ system unless you're building a new Linux distro from scratch. There's probably one there already, but you don't know about this. Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: You can’t just add a package manager yourself.

Comment: So for the first comment, I have been using that as reference but neither of the package managers they list there are included in my host, for whatever reason. Like I said the only knowledge I have on what I am currently using is a RedHat linux host, that I can access via SSH.

Comment: They have the install command but any package managers they do include I wouldn't be able to find with a simple help command. It has all the basic bash commands as well as some other things like python, and perl. But that is as far as my knowledge goes when it comes to the distro.

Comment: I know its unlikely anyone is going to help me out with this but I have access to yum on python, so I might be able to get python running and install some packages from that. It mostly looks like they only give these package managers to their VPS systems and not web hosting, which is what I am on. It makes total sense I just really want to get more for what I pay for. Hope to hear back from you guys!